# How to resolve a proxy object without the extra call to handler.get?

Tags: typescript, promise

I want to create a proxy object that has a set of keys defined in typescript and the returned type is related to the key.

But when I try to resolve this object, it comes an extra call to get with key 'then' (as Promise wants to check if it's a thenable object)

If I test it explicit, I cannot mark the return type.

```js
        get<M extends ServiceKeys<T>>(
          target: {
            [ClientSymbol]: WsRpcClient<T>
          },
          key: M
        ): (
          payload: ServiceRequest<T, M>
        ) => PromiseResult<ServiceRespond<T, M>, ServiceError<T, M>> {
          if (key === 'then') {
            return undefined // I cannot mark this type!
          }
          return payload => {
            return MakeWrapExt(target[ClientSymbol].request(key, payload))
          }
        }
```

Comment: So use `key: M | 'then'` and `undefined | (payload: …) => …`?

Comment: This will break the relation between key and the returned type. If so, every time I use it, I have to check the possibility of returned undefined while it's impossible.

Comment: Then you'll need to overload the `get` method. (I had not assumed you'd use the proxy handler definition to infer the type of the proxy object)

Comment: oh that make sense. I've tried to add definition inside the object and found it not work. It should be done in the type instead of the object.